# Make ESXi use DHCP DNS

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, vmware-esxi

My ESXi host is no longer getting DNS from DHCP server, it caches an IP that was set a very long time ago.

`esxcli network ip interface ipv4 get`

returns

```
Name  IPv4 Address  IPv4 Netmask   IPv4 Broadcast  Address Type  Gateway   DHCP DNS
----  ------------  -------------  --------------  ------------  --------  --------
vmk0  10.0.1.92     255.255.255.0  10.0.1.255      DHCP          10.0.1.1     false
```

How do I make it use the DHCP DNS?

Comment: did you read  7the [manual](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.esxi.install.doc/GUID-D69AB84A-84DA-4AD0-851B-3964CAB53E36.html)?

Comment: @djdomi I'm running standalone ESXi so that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
esxcli network ip interface ipv4 set -i vmk0 --peer-dns=1
```

This will change the `DHCP DNS` setting on interface vmk0 to true.
And your DHCP-configured DNS servers should show up in  /etc/resolv.conf

When I tried the same setting at the `Direct Console` it didn't stick.